# Which control in win 8 phone development is good to be used for showing news list like RSS?

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing win 8 phone apps. some pages of the app are news as list and each news has title, picture and leadin. In the iOs version i created a html string using java script and css and show the html in webview. Now in window version i realized using the same trick with webbrowser is not good since webbrowser scroll and it is difficult to use the Panorama control. which control is the best? should i use listbox instead? Do u have any examples?

(I should mention that i want to show the data in list as soon as i get data from url without realoding the page , thats why i used java script in iOS to load the data in web view without any refresh)

Comment: And of course the cell (each news) should be clickable to show the detail in an other page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For displaying data in a list you generally use ListBox or LongListSelector control.

To display data without reloading, use data binding. The source for the list control should be ObservableCollection<> which can be filled asynchronously. Whenever the collection is changed, your UI will be refreshed.

Comment: I have to make the list and the items in code behind. On the other hand i probably need a custom control with 2 text boxes (for title and leadin) and an image. Now in this case can i still use source or   should i dynamically initiate the user control for each item in ObservableCollection and add the user control as an list item to the list?

Comment: ListBox has ObservableCollection as data source. For customizing the look of each item, use ItemTemplate.